# Is my app's memory usage too high?

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome, memory, google-chrome-devtools

I am looking into my app's memory usage in Chrome in the Task Manager. The app is using ~300MB of "Memory", but only ~50MB of "JavaScript Memory".

Is this a cause for concern? 300MB seems like a lot of memory to be taking up, but 50MB seems reasonable. What else could be taking up the other 250MB, and how can I investigate where that memory is being allocated?